# Is the molecule nitric oxide responsible for healing blood vessels?

Tags: cardiology, blood-circulation, health, blood-pressure, healing

1. Is the molecule nitric oxide responsible for healing blood vessels?
2. How does nitric oxide heal the blood vessels?

I watched a documentary about the healing effects of nitric oxide. In the video I saw a cardiologist show an X-ray picture of one of his damaged heart blood vessels, and then another X-ray picture showing the same heart blood vessel completely healed. He claimed it was due to a radical change in his diet of consuming lots of nitrogen rich vegetables which the body in turn converted to nitric oxide. Is this possible?

Sources :

The original source was the youtube video Forks Over Knifes, however it was recently taken down. I have provide the following links which provide a little bit of information :

http://www.happyhealthylonglife.com/happy_healthy_long_life/2010/06/esselstyn-session.html

http://www.happyhealthylonglife.com/happy_healthy_long_life/2010/12/no.html

Dr. Caldwell Esselstyn was the one who made the statement about heart health and nitric oxide, also showing the xray pictures of one of his colleague cardiologists in the documentary.

Comment: Can you provide a link to that documentary? `NO` causes vasodilation, I have not heard of its role in regeneration. And simply eating nitrogen-rich food will also not increase `NO` (its synthesis is not limited by the availability of nitrogen)

Comment: @WYSIWYG The documentary is called Forks Over Knives. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Here's a review published in Nature, about the regenerative role of NO, followed by an application in 2012 to wound healing.

http://www.nature.com/aps/journal/v26/n3/full/aps200541a.html

http://www.nanomedjournal.com/article/S1549-9634%2812%2900090-1/abstract